# Angular: how to iterate over Immutable js Map inside the template?

Tags: angular, typescript, immutable.js

I want to use Immutable.js inside my angular application because i heard it improve the performance.

So i want to convert my code to use Immutable.js package.

So, my component has a regular typescript Map, which used inside the component's template.
It iterated with *ngFor with keyValue pipe.

When i replace that map to Immutable.Map, the itertation wont work!!

So the question, how to iterate over Immutable.Map inside the template?

Thanks in ahead

Update:
To reproduce the problem.

In app.component.ts:

```typescript
import { Comoonent } from '@angular/core';
import { Map as immuMap } from 'immutable' ;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map', 
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
}) 
export class AppComponent {
  myMap = immuMap({ a: 1, b: 2, c:3});
}
```

In app.component.html :

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of myMap | keyvalue">
  <span>{{ item.key }} : {{ item.value }}</span>
</div>
```

When myMap was a simple typescript Map, it worked.
The code above is after refactor to Immutable.js Map.
And now the `ngFor` wont produce same result as was before....

The result of above code is:

```
__altered : false 
__hash : 
__ownerID: 
_root : [object Object] 
size : 3
```

Comment: Please help responders reproduce your problem by adding code and describe the issue ("won't work" is not a problem description) ([How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). All immutable.js collections support the iterable pattern, so this is likely a problem specific to _your_ code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating in Angular 2 + Immutable.js (using \*ngFor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311753/iterating-in-angular-2-immutable-js-using-ngfor)

Comment: @dube Thank you for your comment! "Iterating in Angular..." doesnt answer my question. Because he use List and i use Map. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since immutable collections are already iterables, <strike>you can just remove the keyvalue pipe.</strike> ngFor can treat immutable.js Map exactly like a native javascript Map.

Entries of Map's [iterator](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/%5BSymbol.iterator%5D) are *arrays* in format `[key, value]`

```
const imMap = Immutable.Map({ a: 1, b: 2, c:3});
for(entry of imMap ) {
  console.log('entry', entry[0], 'is', entry[1]);
}

const nativeMap = new window.Map([['a',1], ['b',2], ['c':3]]);
for(entry of nativeMap ) {
  console.log('entry', entry[0], 'is', entry[1]);
}

// both loops will output:
// entry a is 1
// entry b is 2
// entry c is 3
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. But, first its not exactly what i meant. I want the solution to be inside the template (html) and not in typescript. Because i need to refactor the original 'keyvalue' pipe inside the *ngFor to something else which do the same thing but on Map from Immutable.js. Second, technically i copied your code to my Angular project, and its not compile it.

Comment: If that code does not compile, you are not using ES6 or are missing an Import. It wasn't meant to be a 1:1 copy&pasta solution. But you are right, it should work with the keyvalue pipe. I think your data is not what you think it is. E.g. maybe you have nested objects instead of that simple test-data. It's also not clear what is the key and what the value in your example output. The code for a native JS Map and Immutable.JS Map should work the same way